# C# Regex To Escape Certain Characters

Tags: c#, regex, escaping

How can I escape certain characters in a string with a C# Regex?

```
This is a test for % and ' thing? -> This is a test for \% and \' thing?
```

Comment: What "certain characters" and escape how? For what purpose?

Comment: This is for a MySQL query coming from a C# backend, users can enter % which will return all rows unless I scape it.  I would like to also excape other characters just in case, but try % and ' for now.

Comment: `string.Replace` not good enough?

Comment: make sure you also do backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
    @"(?<!      # Match a position before which there is no
     (?<!\\)    # odd number of backlashes
     \\         # (it's odd if there is one backslash,
     (?:\\\\)*  # followed by an even number of backslashes)
    )
    (?=[%'])    # and which is followed by a % or a '", 
    @"\", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

However, if you're trying to protect yourself against malevolent SQL queries, regex is not the right way to go.

Comment: This seems to add \\% to the character instead of \%

Comment: It adds a single backslash. If you print it, it will be displayed as two backslashes, because `\%` is not a real escape sequence like `\n`. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: What would be the right away to go with MySQL and LIKE?  This is taking a long time to search since % is just being used it is scanning all the tables instead of pulling back just items with %.

Comment: Sorry, that's not my area of expertise. Perhaps something like [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statements)? But you should ask the MySQL experts for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var escapedString = Regex.Replace(input, @"[%']", @"\$1");
```

This is pretty much all you need. Inside the square brackets, you should put every character you wish to escape with a backslash, which may include the backslash character itself.

Comment: This works only if the characters aren't escaped yet. Then you'd unescape them using this method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this could be done with regex in good fashion, but you can simply run a for loop:

```
var specialChars = new char[]{'%',....};
var stream = "";
for (int i=0;i<myStr.Length;i++)
{
   if (specialChars.Contains(myStr[i])
   {
       stream+= '\\'; 
   }
   stream += myStr[i];
}
```

<sub>(1) you can use StringBuilder to prevent from too many string creation.</sub>

Comment: This will unescape already escaped characters. So `foo \% bar` will become `foo \\% bar`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, IMHO, by current problem statement `foo \% bar` should be `foo \\% bar`.

Comment: Not really. He's talking about users being able to provide a string that contains `%` which need to be escaped so they don't mess up his MySQL query. If a user could circumvent that by providing `\%` in the input, it would kind of defeat this purpose. Although, granted, Mike hasn't explicitly specified this. And most probably regex is not the right tool for this.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, I agree (I just see OPs comment), but in this case again is not hard to change for loop, and my main purpose of writing this answer, was offering simple way.